# Display flashdata with codeigniter and flexiauth

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display a (flash) message when a user tries to access a page where he does not have the privileges for.

I have created a controller that loads a view:

```
function index()
{                                                                                       

    // Check user is allowed to open this       

    if ($this->flexi_auth->is_privileged('Wizard'))     
        {       

        $this->load->view('portal/wizard/wizard_view');     

        }       
        else        

        {               
            // Set a custom error message.
            $this->flexi_auth->set_error_message('Sorry, you are not allowed to view this!', TRUE);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->flexi_auth->get_messages());
            redirect('auth_lite/portal');


        }
}
```

If the user does not have the Wizard privilege, it will redirect to the main page (auth_lite/portal) and should display an error message (you are not allowed...).

In my auth_lite controller, I have set this for the portal function:

```
function portal()
{
        if ($this->flexi_auth->is_logged_in())
    {


    // Get any status message that may have been set.
    $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');

    $this->load->view('portal_view');


    }
    else
    {
        redirect('auth/login');
    }

}
```

In my view file, is display the message as this:

```
            <?php if (! empty($message)) { ?>
            <div id="message">
                <?php echo $message; ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

But, the flash message does not showing as expected. I have read the documentation, but I'm not sure what that I am doing wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the below line from auth_lite controller

```
$this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

and change the error message in view

```
 <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')) { ?>
     <div id="message">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
     </div>
 <?php } ?>
```